# Get mean of column values based on another column -R (dpylr)

Tags: r, dplyr

A simple workflow is as follows:

- For each entity, get the `first 3 non-null values` of the column '`PROD_OIL`'
- Calculate the `mean` of corresponding values of the column '`FORCAST_PROD_OIL`'; ignore `NA's` if any.

dput:

```
structure(list(entity= c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A"), REPORT_DATE = structure(c(1623110400, 1623024000, 1622937600, 
1622851200, 1622764800, 1622678400, 1622592000, 1622505600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), PROD_OIL = c("NA", "NA", "265.85000000000002", 
"NA", "272.45999999999998", "NA", "262.32", "NA"), PROD_GAS = c("NA", 
"NA", "2940.78", "NA", "2947.35", "NA", "3237.78", "NA"), FORECAST_PROD_OIL = c(283.71353, 
284.29868, 284.88622, 285.47615, 286.06849, 286.66326, 287.26047, 
287.86013), FORECAST_PROD_GAS = c(3038.99083, 3042.47991, 3045.97701, 
3049.48216, 3052.99539, 3056.51672, 3060.04619, 3063.58382)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I wrote this simple `dpylr` command but I am not getting correct mean value.

```
AvgLast3WT <- dt%>%
  dplyr::arrange(entity,desc(REPORT_DATE))%>%
  dplyr::group_by(entity) %>% 
  dplyr::select(entity,REPORT_DATE,PROD_OIL,PROD_GAS,FORECAST_PROD_OIL, FORECAST_PROD_GAS)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(GetMean= mean(na.omit(with(dt, FORECAST_PROD_OIL[!is.na(PROD_OIL)])[1:3])))%>%
  ungroup()
```

The answer should be 286.07 (mean of red cells below) but I get 285.4!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(PROD_OIL)) %>% 
  group_by(entity) %>% 
  head(3) %>% 
  summarise(Mean=mean(FORECAST_PROD_OIL, na.rm=TRUE))
```

and gives a value of 284.2995.  But your sample data does not contain the values your image suggests it does:

```
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(PROD_OIL)) %>% 
  group_by(entity) %>% 
  head(3) %>% 
  pull(FORECAST_PROD_OIL)
[1] 283.7135 284.2987 284.8862
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  filter(PROD_OIL != "NA") %>%
  group_by(entity) %>%
  top_n(3) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(FORECAST_PROD_OIL)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

which gives:

```
Selecting by FORECAST_PROD_GAS
  entity     Mean
1      A 286.0717
```

In the structure you gave the NA's are strings rather than actual NA values, if in your df they are real NA values replace PROD_OIL != "NA" with !is.na(PROD_OIL)